# Searching strings to ignore multiple matches

Tags: r, string, full-text-search, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with columns names that look like this:

```
d=c("Q.40a-some Text", "Q.40b-some Text", "Q.44a-some Text", "Q.44b-some Text" "Q.44c-some Text" "Q.44d-some Text" ,"Q.4a-some Text", "Q.4b-some Text")
```

I would like to identify the columns which begin with Q.4 and ignore the Q.40, Q.44.

To identify `Q.44` or `Q.40`, for example, is easy. What I do is to use this `"^Q.44"` or "^Q.40" as input to my function. But, this does not work if I do the same for identifying Q.4 - simply because all names begin with Q.4. So, can someone help me on this ?

**UPDATE**

The result I want to pass it, to my function that takes inputs as follows:

```
multichoice<-function(data, question.prefix){

  index<-grep(question.prefix, names(data))    # identifies the index for the available options in Q.12
  cases<-length(index)                # The number of possible options / columns 

  # Identify the range of possible answers for each question 
  # Step 1. Search for the min in each col and across each col choose the min
  # step 2. Search for the max in each col and across each col choose the max 

  mn<-min(data[,index[1:cases]], na.rm=T)
  mx<-max(data[,index[1:cases]], na.rm=T)
  d = colSums(data[, index] != 0, na.rm = TRUE)  # The number of elements across column vector, that are different from zero. 

  vec<-matrix(,nrow=length(mn:mx),ncol=cases)

  for(j in 1:cases){
    for(i in mn:mx){
      vec[i,j]=sum(data[, index[j]] == i, na.rm = TRUE)/d[j]  # This stores the relative responses for option j for the answer that is i
    }
  }

  vec1<-as.data.frame(vec)
  names(vec1)<-names(data[index])
  vec1<-t(vec1)
  return(vec1)
}
```

And the way I use my funtion is this

```
q4 <-multichoice(df2,"^Q.4")
```

Where by "^Q.4" I intend to identify the columns for `Q.4`, and `df2` is my dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method using `grep`:
To return the indices

```
grep("^Q\\.4[^0-9]", d)
```

Of the column names:

```
grep("^Q\\.4[^0-9]", d, value=T)
```

This works because [^0-9] says any character that is not a number, so we match Q.4 literally, then match strings with any non number.

I believe what you want in the mn statement in your function is

```
mn <- min(sapply(data[,index], min, na.rm=T), na.rm=T)
```

`sapply` moves through the columns selected by index selected `grep` and finds the minimum with `min`. Then, `min` is applied to all of the columns.

Comment: Thanks Imo, this is cool. I really struggle a bit with regular expressions and the documentation is really bad for a beginner like me. Can you please help me how I utilize your method, in order to pass the result to my function? I have edited my question accordingly in order to see what my function needs as inputs.

Comment: My favorite regex site is [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). They have lots of great info. What you are asking now should be posed in a new question, but I'll take a look.

Comment: I updated my answer to give a method for calculating the minimum. If you need more, please consider asking a new question, that also includes some sample data (using `dput`) for people to use to test their solutions.

Comment: One, solution that I am thinking is just to rename the columns `Q.4a-some Text"` and  `"Q.4b-some Text` to `Q.4.a-some Text"` and  `"Q.4.b-some Text` - notice that I added a dot after the number 4. So, I can simple use as input to my function `"^Q.4."` . What do you think ?

Comment: It doesn't matter to `grep`. This sounds like more trouble than its worth, especially if the regex that I gave above does the job.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `stringr`,

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(d, 'Q.[0-9]+') == 'Q.4'
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

#or 

d[str_extract(d, 'Q.[0-9]+') == 'Q.4']
#[1] "Q.4a-some Text" "Q.4b-some Text"
```

If the format is always the same (i.e. Q.[0-9]...) then we can use `gsub`

```
gsub('\\D', '', d) == 4
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```